# Unnest both arrays simultaneously and select elements from the corresponding positions

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I have data in a table `table` like the following:

```
id1     id2        some_sources        time_per_source  
1        3          "["a","b"]"          [0,31345]  
2        4          "["a","b"]"          [0,29225]
```

I want to create a table such that

```
id1     id2       some_sources     time_per_source    source      time
1       3         "["a","b"]"        [0,31345]          "a"          0
1       3         "["a","b"]"        [0,31345]          "b"        31345    
2       4         "["a","b"]"        [0,29225]          "a"           0
2       4         "["a","b"]"        [0,29225]          "b"        29225
```

How can I do that in BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Google big query;

```
WITH your_data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id1, 3 AS id2, '["a","b"]' AS some_sources, '[0,31345]' AS time_per_source UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, '["a","xb"]', '[0,29225]'
) 
SELECT
  id1,
  id2,
  some_sources,
  time_per_source,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(some_sources, '$') AS source,
  (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(time_per_source, '$')) AS time
FROM your_data
```

You can replace the **table1** in the **your_data** CTE with your table name.

```
WITH your_data AS (
  SELECT id1, id2, some_sources, time_per_source FROM table1
) 
SELECT
  id1,
  id2,
  some_sources,
  time_per_source,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(some_sources, '$') AS source,
  (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(time_per_source, '$')) AS time
FROM your_data
```

Comment: Can it be done without specifying the rows? The table has 100s of rows, I just put two here as an example

Comment: Yes you can I added those two records as a table you can replace them with the table you are using
Replace the below with the columns and the table you want to

SELECT 1 AS id1, 3 AS id2, '["a","b"]' AS some_sources, '[0,31345]' AS time_per_source UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 4, '["a","xb"]', '[0,29225]'

Comment: This is what I tried:
`
WITH your_data AS (
  SELECT table.id1 AS id1, table.id2 AS id2, table.some_sources AS some_sources, table.time_per_source AS time_per_source
) 
SELECT
  id1,
  id2,
  some_sources,
  time_per_source,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(some_sources, '$') AS source,
  (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(time_per_source, '$')) AS time
FROM your_data
`
I get: `No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY for argument types: ARRAY<INT32>, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(STRING, [STRING])`

Comment: You have not mentioned the table name within the your_data CTE if you can replace table_1 with the actual table name

WITH your_data AS (
  SELECT id1,  id2, some_sources, time_per_source 
  FROM table_1 
) 
SELECT
  id1,
  id2,
  some_sources,
  time_per_source,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(some_sources, '$') AS source,
  (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(time_per_source, '$')) AS time
FROM your_data;

Comment: @AsmitaPoddar, I have added option two in the answer you can replace the table name with yours. Check the Answer I just modified